# How can i write the serial port incoming data into text file (.txt)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How I can write the serial port incoming data into text file(.txt).. The data write should have one hour interval time. 
Following this the serial read data code:

```
void MainWindow::readData()
{
     QByteArray data = serial->readAll();
     QDataStream stream(data);

     double value;
     stream>>value;
     console->putData(data);
     qDebug()<<value;
}
```

I have tried this way but failed

```
void Write(QString Filename)
{
     QFile mFile(Filename);

     if(!mFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file for writing";
        return;
    }


    QTextStream out(&mFile);
    out << data;
    mFile.flush();
    mFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `QByteArray` for receiving and use signal `readyRead()` to call receive function when data is received.

```
QSerialPort *serialPort= new QSerialPort();
connect(serialPort, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &MainWindow::receiveData_WriteToFile);
```

This function read data and write it in file.

```
void MainWindow::receiveData_WriteToFile()
{
    if (serialPort->isOpen())
    {
        QByteArray DataReceived;
        QFile LogFile("D:/data.txt");
        if(!LogFile.open(QFile::Append | QFile::Text))
        {
            //Can't Open Log File.
        }
        if(serialPort->bytesAvailable())
        {
            DataReceived = serialPort->readAll();//All Data Received Successfully.
            if(DataReceived.size() > 0)
            {
                if(LogFile.isOpen())
                {
                    QTextStream in(&LogFile);
                    in << DataReceived;
                }

                LogFile.close();
            }
            else
            {
                //Fail To Receive Data.
            }
        }
        LogFile.close();
    }
}
```

[readyRead()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) : This signal is emitted once every time new data is available for reading from the device's current read channel. It will only be emitted again once new data is available, such as when a new payload of network data has arrived on your network socket, or when a new block of data has been appended to your device.

output file:

[image: Screenshot]

This is a sample project for your question on [github download here.](https://github.com/FarhadProfessional/QSerialPort)

Comment: thank for the help. you have added browse option, what is the use of that?, and i have to give a time interval of one hour that serial receiving data should write into the text file with data and time ?

Comment: @explorer104 I used browse button to get file location directory. `getExistingDirectory`, and Use QTimer to receive data like that. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html